# paypal ipn item_number error

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

Last week, paypal ipn stopped working.

I use the item_number in a php script with the request sent by paypal.
Before last week all worked fine, but since last week paypal sends me the ipn without item_number. All the other fields are ok, but item_number is empty. I've also seen the ipn log and the ipn send when someone is buying something doesn't work but if someone does a reclaim paypal sends me an ipn with the information of the reclaim and the item_number.

So why when someone buys something, there's no item number, and when someone does a reclaim, there is?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. PayPal has send the data with a other key.
The old key was: item_numer, the new key is: item_number**1** !
The same with item_name --> item_name1 and quantity --> quantity1.

Best
Jan